# Show Hide Silverlight Controls from the page

Tags: silverlight

I have a dataGrid control on the page and below this grid there are some text boxes. in some conditions I dont want to display the grid on the page. For this I have used

dg.Visibilty = Visibilty.Collapse;

It will successfully hide the datagrid, which is fine, but the space that is consumned by the grid is still disply on the page, what I want is when my  grid is hidden then controls will shift up automatically just like style=display:none ;

Thanks

Comment: I want to autoShrink the row when dataGrid is hidden

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work fine.

It might be that the container which contains your data grid might have some height width assigned.

Comment: No Height or width is assigned to control, it is Auto. I think i have not put the controls in any row or column, do you think that might be the problem???

Comment: I want to autoShrink the row when dataGrid is hidden